# Why the thumbnail of article is not showing while sharing in fb?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook opengraph API in my html page meta tags.

I've given the url of the image in the `og:image` property, but when I share the page in FB, it's not showing the image.

But, after the first time, when I share the article again, the image appears.

Can any one explain why it is happening?

When I share the same article in whatsapp it is showing the image for the first time only.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a cache of scraped links, and the first time you're sharing the link, the image isn't available in FB cache.

You can use the [FB precaching tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching) to "force" a first scrape of your page, or you can add `og:image` meta tags to your page:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300"/>
```

Read the link above for more information about FB sharing.

Be sure to check how FB "see" your page using the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: i have added these two tags before.but then also it is not working.if i add these two lines it is displaying random image which i have in my html page

Comment: Try with the FB debugger and check how FB see your page, or if there are errors.

Comment: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. this is the error coming when i debug from fb debugger.

Comment: Probably it's seeing a older version of your page or your image URL is wrong: is your webserver serving the page with the og:image tag? Is the image url an absolute URL?

Comment: it is an absolute url only. now it is coming. while sharing in fb same article image is coming.but while sharing in whatsapp same article image is not coming.do you know why it is happening? like fb what will be use by whatsapp?

Comment: This is another problem, please create another question for this.

Comment: do you know the answer?please tell me